# PHP Soap request tag empty

Tags: php, xml, soap, request

I'm trying to use php for soap calls to an ASP.net (I'm pretty sure that's the server).

I have issues with a request being sent. I believe this is the important part of the wsdl. (note that I'm inexperienced with SOAP).

```
<s:element name="GetAssetDetails">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="request" nillable="true" type="tns:AssetDetailsRequest"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="AssetDetailsRequest">
<s:complexContent mixed="false">
<s:extension base="tns:RequestBase">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AssetGuid" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AssetId" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AssetName" type="s:string"/><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestedInfos" nillable="true" type="tns:AssetInfos"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:extension>
</s:complexContent>
</s:complexType>
```

The following XML is giving a correct response (as test I've overwritten __doRequest and put this as the full xml request)

```
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
  <GetAssetDetails xmlns="http://xxxx/...">
    <request>
      <AssetName>arg1</AssetName>
      <RequestedInfos>option1 option2</RequestedInfos>
    </request>
  </GetAssetDetails>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';
```

So I actually don't need the AssetGuid. However it seems that the WSDL says I have to (however I'm not sure if I interpret this correctly).

Now what I do:

```
$ap_param = array(
     // 'AssetGuid' => 'EUAUDYEHDOUIDFHADHSJLKW', // Tried with and without this, random value
    'AssetName'      => 'arg1',
    'RequestedInfos' => 'option1 option2'
);
$info = $soapClient->__call("GetAssetDetails", array($ap_param));
```

However in the XML that goes over the wire the request tag is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/..."
<soap12:Body>
<GetAssetDetails>
  <request xsi:nil="true"/>
</GetAssetDetails></soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

The response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
    <soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value></soap:Code>
    <soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.</soap:Text></soap:Reason>
    <soap:Detail />
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong that the request element is empty and doesn't hold my parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SoapClient::_*call is deprecated try to use  SoapClient::*_soapCall instead of it. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Tried that: same outcome. Can someone tell me if this is an xml, a wsdl or what sort of error this is? I pass the arguments. Is the code wrong that I use? Why is the request params being left out?

Comment: What you mean: soapClient object done? I have an object. Otherwise I wouldn't see xml data using wireshark going to the soap server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Mournfully my solution was to speak with my provider to let them know that I cannot comply the WSDL if I remove that element.

Anyways I guess you could always implement some SOAP solution based in on this http://codeidol.com/community/php/calling-a-soap-method-without-wsdl/20070/